# DIV Overlapping Content

Tags: html, css

I created a `div` that occupies the whole view-port and want the user to scroll down to see more content but after `div`, when I created an `h1` tag the heading is being overlapped by the `div`.

What I'm doing wrong?

Link to JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/cycse638/3/
I want it like this - [Result expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QzKw.png)

Comment: It's 'overlapped' because you have set `position: absolute` to your `div#background`. When you set a position to an element, that element is taken out of the normal flow and the elements below it are moved to the top of the page.

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

you can either use z-index to lower and raise each element or change the opacity of the div, which will still obscure the header to a degree. or you can simply put the header tag within the div like so: `<div id="background"><h1>weadfs</h1></div>`

```css
#background {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: #eee;
  z-index: -1;
}

h1 {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="background"></div>
<h1>weadfs</h1>
```

```css
#background {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="background"></div>
<h1>weadfs</h1>
```

```css
#background {
  z-index: -1;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background: green;
}

h1 {
  height: 90vh;
  position: relative;
  top: 200vh;
}
```

```html
<div id="background"></div>
<h1>weadfs</h1>
```

Comment: I don't want to layer them. I want them to be like a parallax layer the 'DIV' with ID background will be the intro to my page and there will be a scroll down logo at bottom.

Comment: @mrnobody you should probably clarify your question if that's the case. i still don't understand what you want to do...

Comment: @mrnobody, in that case, just set 
`h1{
  margin-top: 100%;
}` 

This will place your h1 tag below the div element.

Answer (score -1):

**About `position:absolute`**

As @Mers stated, when you set `position:absolute` to an element, that element is taken out of the normal flow.  As such, all other items below it will be positioned like there was nothing above them (the result: these items are pushed up the document-- in your case H1 pushes itself up beneath your #background).

As such, you'd want `position:relative` (which often the default), for your #background, so that it will flow together with the other elements in your page (since you said you want to scroll to your H1).

**You said `occupy the whole view-port`**

If you want your upper div to be exactly the height of your viewport, then use 100vh, not 100%, for your height. The difference is that 100% will make it occupy all available space (i.e. everything), while the latter only makes it occupy the length equal to the available screen (i.e. not the entire document).

**Editing your fiddle**

Okay. so here's your modified fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/cycse638/5/

...with CSS modified in consideration of the points above. Go to the fiddle, then scroll down the sample output and you'll see that it looks like what you posted [here](https://s2.postimg.org/kssb6th3d/Untitled_Diagram.png).

note: You can disregard the flex rules I put in your H1.  They're there so that it'll look like the one in your diagram.  what's important is your #background is positioned relative, with a height of 100vh.

Hope this helps!

Comment: could you guys let me know what the downvote was for?